# Electron App Loses Shadow When Set To Transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I'm trying to create a window with rounded corners using Electron. I've managed to achieve this by setting the BrowserWindow setting `transparent` to `true`, and then creating a div the size of the body with a border radius of 10px.

However, the issue is that setting the transparent setting to true seems to remove the shadow that Windows 10 applies to the window. The issue doesn't seem to be present on macOS, as the shadow is applied regardless of the transparency setting.

I've tried also setting the BrowserWindow setting `hasShadow` to `true`, but it makes no difference.

Is there any way to create a rounded window in electron, without loosing the window shadow in the process?

Comment: Why not create the shadow effect yourself when running on window10?

Comment: Do you mean create the shadow using CSS? If so, that's not really a solution sadly as the shadow will not extend past the bounds of the window.

Comment: Well you would need to make a frameless window and then add the border yourself. E.g. make the window non resizable first and then define the resize borders if you want them with a slight offset inside the window...

Comment: Having the window offset isn't really practical - if you want to snap the window to the left or right of the screen, or fullscreen the window then there will be a gap between the window border and the screen edge.

Comment: That's why Windows uses an OffscreenMargin of 8px in Win10. You can look at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8728#issuecomment-282879250 for further context. I do not know how snapping is handled, though.

Comment: @Alex Did you found solution?